# Transition delay for two diferent elements reverse when hover out

Tags: css

I need a transition where the hover sequence is ABBA instead of ABAB.

Here's a fiddle I made to demo this:

https://jsfiddle.net/m8vrLtx7/1/

This is the code:

```
div{
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 3rem;
  position: relative;
}

div:before,
div:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

div:after{
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

div:before{
  width: calc(100% - 1rem);
  height: calc(100% - 1rem);
  top: .5rem;
  left: .5rem;
  background: pink;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-delay: .1s;
}

div:hover:before,
div:hover:after{
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

What I need is the inner circle (the pink one) to animate last, but on hover out I want it to go first.

Is there any way to do this, CSS only?

Answer (score 0):

You should use css `@keyframes`. Then you can use `animation` which has quite nice properties to help you achive this.

Check out [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)  and [this link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) for keyframes

**HINT**

You can use `animation-direction: reverse` property

Comment: How? I can't think of a way to do it with animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a transition-delay in both “directions”, by specifying different values for the normal and the :hover state. Each one will apply when the element gets *into* the respective state.

I increased the values from your example by factor 10 here, so that we can more easily observe what is going on, but you can simply speed that up again.

So you just delay the transition on the pink :before circle, when the element gets *into* the :hover state. And the other way around for the blue one.

```css
div{
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 3rem;
  position: relative;
}

div:before,
div:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 3s;
}

div:after{
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

div:before{
  width: calc(100% - 1rem);
  height: calc(100% - 1rem);
  top: .5rem;
  left: .5rem;
  background: pink;
  z-index: 2;
}

div:hover:before,
div:hover:after{
  transform: scale(1);
}
div:hover:before {
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
div:hover:after {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```